# how to add an object literal to an array using a variable that holds the array name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm having trouble getting a new object literal into an array. When I use the array name, everything works. But when I switch the code to use a variable that is holding the array name, it doesn't work.

I've got 6 arrays like the following, and they're listed on my page. A click saves the name of the array clicked into a variable called whichList.

Here are three of the arrays:

```
student0 = [
  {
    status: "completed",
    goal: "go to store",
    duedate: "November 1",
    datecreated: ""
  }, {
    status: "completed",
    goal: "buy beer",
    duedate: "November 2",
    datecreated: ""
  }
];

student1 = [
  {
    status: "completed",
    goal: "go to the beach",
    duedate: "November 7"
  }, {
    status: "completed",
    goal: "swim without drowning",
    duedate: "November 8",
    datecreated: ""
  }
];

student2 = [
  {
    status: "completed",
    goal: "fly a plane",
    duedate: "November 11",
    datecreated: ""
  }, {
    status: "completed",
    goal: "don't crash",
    duedate: "November 12",
    datecreated: ""
  }
];
```

Here's the working code, which is specifying the array name directly. It shows my updated array in the console after the click:

```
$('#savegoal').click(function() {
  datecreated = new Date();
  student0[student0.length] = {
    status: "pending",
    goal: "\"" + $('#thegoal').val() + "\"",
    duedate: "\"" + $('#thedeadline').val() + "\"",
    datecreated: "\"" + datecreated + "\""
  };
  return console.log(student0);
});
```

Here's the non-working code. I want to use the whichList variable.

I've used console.log to check that the variable is showing the correct array name at the beginning of the function. All good there. But all I get in the console is the array variable, not the contents of the array as I do in the working version.

```
$('#savegoal').click(function() {
  datecreated = new Date();
  whichList[whichList.length] = {
    status: "pending",
    goal: "\"" + $('#thegoal').val() + "\"",
    duedate: "\"" + $('#thedeadline').val() + "\"",
    datecreated: "\"" + datecreated + "\""
  };
  return console.log(whichList);
});
```

Comment: Don't put the name of the array in `whichList`, assign the array itself.

Comment: Also, any time you have a bunch of variables named XXX0, XXX2, etc. they probably should be an array, not separate variables. Then `whichList` can just be the index into this array.

Comment: Another thing: `array[array.length] = val` should be `array.push(val)`.

Comment: You don't need all those escaped doublequotes, either.

Comment: Okay, I got rid of the escapes and went with push(), but I'm not sure how to assign the array. Trying the solutions below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window[whichList]`, since the array variable is presumably in the global/window scope:

```
var whichList = "student0";
var theList = window[whichList];
theList[theList.length] = { ... };   // consider using instead: theList.push( { ... })
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. But do I need to worry about depending on the global/window scope? You used the word presumably and that's making me think I'll end up walking into whatever issues are hidden in that word.

Comment: @charliemagee use of the global scope can cause maintainability problems as a code base grows in size.  If you find yourself using many global variables, it's a good idea to consider passing around references instead.

Comment: @charliemagee that said, there's no inherent problem with it.  If you declare an object without `var`, then it will always remain there in global scope until you remove it.

Comment: I chose this as the correct answer because it immediately worked. But after trying out the other ideas I began to feel like I had started off on the wrong track. I ended up simplifying things by creating a goalsArray, and then adding a username to each goal. After that I simply did a grep on the array to return the list I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A direct answer to your question :

```
var wichList = null;
$('#savegoal').click(function() {
  if (wichList == null){
      alert('No list selected');
  }
  // don't forget the "var", otherwise "datecreated"
  // will actually be a global variable
  var datecreated = new Date();
  // ".push()" adds the given value at the end of the array
  wichList.push({
    status: "pending",
    goal: "\"" + $('#thegoal').val() + "\"",
    duedate: "\"" + $('#thedeadline').val() + "\"",
    datecreated: "\"" + datecreated + "\""
  });
  return console.log(wichList);
});

//somewhere else in your code :
if (somecond) {
    wichList = student0;
} elseif (somecond) {
    wichList = student1;
} else {
    wichList = null;
}
```

The above code works : in javascript, an `array` variable is actually a *reference* to the array's content

```
var a = [];
var b = a;
// b an a are now references to the same array,
// any modification to a will be "seen" by b, and vice versa :
a.push(1);
b.push(2);
// a == b == [1,2]
```

---

However, given the names of your "student" variables, these lists should probably be stored in an array :

```
var students = [];

students[0] = [{
    status: "completed",
    goal: "go to store",
    duedate: "November 1",
    datecreated: ""
  }, {
    status: "completed",
    goal: "buy beer",
    duedate: "November 2",
    datecreated: ""
  }];

students[1] = [ ...
```

You can now use the index in this array as a way to identify a student, maybe with an extra select :

```
<select id="student">
    <option value="0">student 0</option>
    <option value="1">student 1</option>
    ...
</select>
```

and use it in your `click` callback :

```
$('#savegoal').click(function() {
  var datecreated = new Date();
  var i = $('#student').val();
  students[i].push({
    status: "pending",
    goal: "\"" + $('#thegoal').val() + "\"",
    duedate: "\"" + $('#thedeadline').val() + "\"",
    datecreated: "\"" + datecreated + "\""
  });
  return console.log(students[i]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

First, use an array instead of separate variables:

```
var student = [
    [{
        status: "completed",
        goal: "go to store",
        duedate: "November 1",
        datecreated: ""
    }, {
        status: "completed",
        goal: "buy beer",
        duedate: "November 2",
        datecreated: ""
    }],
    [{
        status: "completed",
        goal: "go to the beach",
        duedate: "November 7"
    }, {
        status: "completed",
        goal: "swim without drowning",
        duedate: "November 8",
        datecreated: ""
    }],
    [{
        status: "completed",
        goal: "fly a plane",
        duedate: "November 11",
        datecreated: ""
    }, {
        status: "completed",
        goal: "don't crash",
        duedate: "November 12",
        datecreated: ""
    }],
    ...
];
```

Then , `whichList` should be an index into the array (i.e. a number from 0 to 5) rather than the name of a variable, and you can do:

```
$('#savegoal').click(function() {
    datecreated = new Date().toString();
    student[whichList].push({
        status: "pending",
        goal: $('#thegoal').val(),
        duedate: $('#thedeadline').val(),
        datecreated: datecreated
    });
});
```

You don't need to concatenate all those `"\""` -- quotes are part of the notation when typing string literals, you don't need them what you're getting the strings from variables or expressions.

Here's how you can do it if you want to use student IDs as the key to finding each student:

```
var student = {};
student[student0] = [
    {
        status: "completed",
        goal: "go to store",
        duedate: "November 1",
        datecreated: ""
    }, {
        status: "completed",
        goal: "buy beer",
        duedate: "November 2",
        datecreated: ""
    }];
student[student1] = [
    {
        status: "completed",
        goal: "go to the beach",
        duedate: "November 7"
    }, {
        status: "completed",
        goal: "swim without drowning",
        duedate: "November 8",
        datecreated: ""
    }];
student[student2] = [
    {
        status: "completed",
        goal: "fly a plane",
        duedate: "November 11",
        datecreated: ""
    }, {
        status: "completed",
        goal: "don't crash",
        duedate: "November 12",
        datecreated: ""
    }];

$('#savegoal').click(function() {
    datecreated = new Date();
    push(student[whichStudentId],{
        status: "pending",
        goal: $('#thegoal').val(),
        duedate: $('#thedeadline').val(),
        datecreated: datecreated
    });
    console.log(whichList);
});
```

Comment: Hmmm. I'm getting an error with this that disappears from the console before I can read it. But I'll need to use studentIDs to track the data. Shouldn't the array be something like this: studentList = [
  student0 = [
    {
      category: "personal",
      datecreated: "",
      duedate: "November 1",
      goal: "go to store",
      goalid: 1,
      status: "completed"
    }, {

Comment: No, that's not the syntax for arrays. But if you want to track by student IDs instead of by array indexes, you could make `student` an object whose keys are student IDs.